# access logged in name in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to access the username (a.k.a. the username I enter when I log on to my windows machine) in R shiny.

Here is my **ui.r**:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(


  sidebarPanel(
    #sliderInput("n", "Number of plots", value=1, min=1, max=5)
  ),

  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("user")
  )
))
```

here is my **server.r**:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {


  output$user <- renderText({
    paste(sep = "",
          "protocol: ", session$clientData$url_protocol, "\n",
          "hostname: ", session$clientData$url_hostname, "\n",
          "pathname: ", session$clientData$url_pathname, "\n",
          "port: ",     session$clientData$url_port,     "\n",
          "user: ",   session$user,   "\n"
    )
  })
  })#end of server
```

You can see I am trying to use `session$user` but when I run this I see on the bottom of the page

```
protocol: http:
hostname: 127.0.0.1
pathname: /
port: 5616
user:
```

So the user is blank.

Do you know how I would access the the login I use to log into my Windows machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear how your shiny is running and what user you are referring to. However you can access the username in windows using:

```
Sys.getenv()["USERNAME"]
```

Answer (score 2):

@user3022875 `Sys.getenv` on **USERNAME** above will work for Windows, but not all machines. You might want to host your app on shinyapps.io, or another server, in time.

I wrote this script to help me as one of my users was on a Linux machine.  I also noticed from help files Unix machines may need **LOGNAME**.

```
GetUserName <- function() {
  # Returns user name of computer with twist for Unix
  # Args
  #   none
  # Returns
  #  string of user login name

  x <- Sys.info()[["user"]]

  # if blank try other methods
  if (is.null(x) | x == "") {
    # On windows machines
    Sys.getenv("USERNAME")  
  } else {
    # from helpfiles for Unix
    Sys.getenv("LOGNAME")  
  }

  # Could get something but it is unknown error
  if (identical(x, "unknown")) {
    warning("unknown returned")
  }

  return(x)
}
```

You could add this function to your server.R or global.R. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try either:

```
Sys.getenv()["USERNAME"][[1]]
```

or

```
Sys.getenv("USERNAME")
```

This will definitely output the Windows login name. If you want to wrap it as a function you can use the following:

```
user_name <- function() {
return(Sys.getenv()["USERNAME"][[1]])
### or return(Sys.getenv("USERNAME"))
}
```